# UDP Multithreading Server Design issue

Tags: java, multithreading, udp

I am writing a program for UDP Multithreading server.I have written quote based on the inputs and psuedo codes which i have taken from the Stack overflow.When i execute my program my computer is hanging up.Could anyone please correct the issue with the below code and provide me optimal solution for writing a UDP server which handles Multithreading.

```
public class MyownServer extends JFrame{

    private JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new MyownServer();
    }
    public MyownServer(){
         add(new JScrollPane(jta), BorderLayout.CENTER);
         setVisible(true);
         setSize(400, 400);
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         setTitle("Server");// It is necessary to show the frame here!
        try{
        DatagramSocket firstsocket = new DatagramSocket(8100);;
        int id = 0;
        while (true) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            DatagramPacket receivePacket =
                     new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            ClientServiceThread cliThread = new ClientServiceThread(firstsocket, receivePacket);
          cliThread.start();
        }
        }
        catch(IOException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
         }
        }
    }

public class ClientServiceThread extends Thread {
     private JTextArea jta = new JTextArea();
          DatagramPacket packet;;
              boolean running = true;
              DatagramPacket sendPacket;
              DatagramSocket socket;;

              byte[] buf;

              ClientServiceThread(DatagramSocket socket,DatagramPacket packet) {
                  this.socket=socket;
                 this.packet=packet;
              }
                public void run()
                {
                    try {
                     // Compute and process
                        byte[] data = new byte[256]; 
                        DatagramPacket response = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
                        socket.receive(packet);

                     double rate = Double.parseDouble(new String(buf).trim());
                        sendPacket.setAddress(packet.getAddress());
                        sendPacket.setPort(packet.getPort());
                        socket.send(sendPacket);
                        socket.receive(packet);
                        double years = Double.parseDouble(new String(buf).trim());
                        socket.send(sendPacket);
                        socket.receive(packet);
                        double loan = Double.parseDouble(new String(buf).trim());

                        double monthlyPayment = loan * (rate / 1200) / (1 - (Math.pow(1 / (1 + (rate / 1200)), years * 12))); 
                        double totalPayment = monthlyPayment * years * 12;

                        sendPacket.setData(new Double((double)(monthlyPayment * 100) / 100.00).toString().getBytes());
                        socket.send(sendPacket);
                        socket.receive(packet);
                        sendPacket.setData(new Double((double)(totalPayment * 100) / 100.00).toString().getBytes());
                        socket.send(sendPacket);
                        socket.close();
                      jta.append("Interest Rate is " + rate + '\n');
                     jta.append("Number Of years " + years + '\n');
                     jta.append("Loan Amount is " + loan + '\n');
                     jta.append("Monthly payment " + monthlyPayment + '\n');
                     jta.append("Total Payment " + totalPayment + '\n');
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
                  }
```

I appreciate your help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note, "hanging" is a synonym for "freezing" - which is suspect is what you intended looking at the code. "hanging up" means to terminate a call, so in this context it could mean that your program randomly closes the UDP socket. This is confusing - please correct to remove ambiguity.

Comment: When i run the program i am getting the server popup and i am not getting any error in the console but my laptop is not responding as before.It sometimes completely freezes and i am restarting laptop again.I hope this clears the above question

Answer (score 2):

This section just sits there creating thread after thread forever.

```
            while (true) {
                byte[] buf = new byte[256];
                DatagramPacket receivePacket
                        = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                ClientServiceThread cliThread = new ClientServiceThread(firstsocket, receivePacket);
                cliThread.start();
            }
```

You should use a [ThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html).

Comment: Could you expand your answer to show how the OP should implement the threadpool to the application?

Comment: @Ferrybig that's out of scope and too broad.

Comment: Yet another reason why people should copy chunks of code off SO and stick them together...

Answer (score 0):

Your server socket should wait to receive connections from the clients inside a infinite loop. You do have a loop but you are missing a receive function call in there.

The receive call shall return the client socket on which then you can communicate with the client henceforth.

Here's a complete example for working with DatagramSockets

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/datagrams/clientServer.html